# Finding PL/SQL source of row deletion

Tags: debugging, plsql, oracle10g

I've inherited some nasty PL/SQL code in a 10g database which is deleting rows from a particular table improperly.

I know the deletion is occurring because I've set up a trigger that records the row details when a row is deleted.

Obviously the simple answer would be "search for "delete from."  However, just one of the procedures involved contains 18 pages of PL/SQL and the procedure has around 25 parameters.  The deletes in the code specify what rows to delete via some very complex joins which involve many parameters.  It's nasty, nasty code that will take some time to debug.

Are there tools in Oracle which might help me pinpoint the statement causing the delete?

What would be perfect is a trigger that records a stack trace on deletion, but I don't think that exists.

I've been told that turning on trace may help, but it may also be quite an exercise depending on how much trace output there is.

I also thought of perhaps locking the table and seeing where an error is thrown, but given that the code undoubtedly does lots of inserts before the deletion, I don't know the error would be any help.

All thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a package spec to your application that keeps a simple state variable, e.g.

```
create or replace package app_state is
  g_state varchar2(30);
end;
```

Before each delete in the PL/SQL code, set this state to something that allows you to identify the delete statement, e.g.

```
app_state.g_state := 'delete 1';
delete ... very ... complex ... stuff ...
app_state.g_state := 'delete 2';
delete ... more ... complex ... stuff ...
```

You can read and save the value of app_state.g_state in the trigger you already have.

This allows you to monitor/log which delete statement deleted which row.

Comment: Accepted for being simple, yet effective.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're working with a large ETL process? I would probably start to go about this by:

- Copying a (very) small subset of the source data into a QA or development environment, including a few rows I know will be deleted, and a few that I know won't (perhaps data from a day-ago backup).
- Run the code using the PL/SQL debugger with breakpoints at each SQL "delete" statement. Check to see if your rows are still there after each "delete" occurs. This is a lot easier to do with an IDE like TOAD, but can be done using just oracle technologies. See http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/plsql/debug.html.
- There is also the PL/SQL trace, as you mentioned, which can be useful for identifying issues like this in smaller pieces of code. These files get very big very fast, so it may be wise to do the trace with the small subset of data as before.
- For an exception stack trace, take a look here as well - http://paranoid-engineering.blogspot.com/2008/07/oracle-exception-handling-stack-trace.html
  You may be able to add some additional code to handle exceptions and then "lock" the table to generate that "delete" exception

You may have to resort to the old standby - DBMS_OUTPUT after each "DELETE" sql statement.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into setting up auditing on that table, at least while you're trying to figure out exactly whats happening.  10g has fine grained auditing and DML auditing.  Here's a helpful [link](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/Auditing_10gR2.php).

Here's a more [complete example](http://www.databasejournal.com/img/2006/10/jsc_10g_Security_Listing1.html#List0103), showing detailed output as well.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The function `DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_CALL_STACK` creates a stack trace of the current execution. You could call it from your trigger and write the result to a separate table (in an autonomous transaction).

Comment: Does trigger call stack have anything to do with SP's call stack. Supposedly a trigger is an anonymous block with its own stack, and it's not directly called from the SP.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's a separate stack. So my approach won't work.